# Python urlencode (API)

Tags: python

**I'm a total noob to python so don't be too harsh :)**

I'm trying to make a script that gets information from an API
I've used this code:

```
import urllib.parse
import requests

main_api = 'https://api.truckersmp.com/v2/player/'
id = '1'
url = main_api + urllib.parse.urlencode({'id': id})
print(url)

json_data = requests.get(url).json()
print(json_data)
```

This works but my url becomes this:

> https://api.truckersmp.com/v2/player/id=1

while it needs to be this:

> https://api.truckersmp.com/v2/player/1

So there doesn't need to be an ID tag.

How do i do this?

Comment: `url = main_api + id`?

Comment: Ok this makes me feel dumb hahah thanks you can post it in answers :) @zvone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using urllib.parse.urlencode, you can use the "+" operator to concatenate the strings:

```
main_api = 'https://api.truckersmp.com/v2/player/'
id = '1'
url = main_api + id
```

Or, you an use the `join()` method to combine the two:

```
main_api = 'https://api.truckersmp.com/v2/player/'
id = '1'
url = "".join([main_api, id])
```

Either will result in the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

main_api = 'https://api.truckersmp.com/v2/player/'
id = '1'
url = main_api + id
print(url)

json_data = requests.get(url).json()
print(json_data)
```